# Assign variable to 'import'ed ES2015 module

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Let's say I have module like this,

```
//mul.js
export default function (v) {
  return v * v;
}
```

use like follows.

```
import mul from 'mul.js'
console.log(mul(3))
```

The question is, how can I assign module `mul` to another variable(or object)? I don't want to pollute namespace for every modules.

Comment: It looks like there is no such a way.

Comment: I added an answer below which I think might help you solve your issue. Tell me if I understood your overarching problem correctly.

Comment: I think your intermediary file approach is claver in this case. At the same time, I somewhat misunderstood what module have to be - mostly module needs a namespace that is general enough to consider as a individual module. So using `import * as utils from 'path/to/utils.js'` and `export function mul () {...}` is appropriate in my case. You solved my problem anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prevent polluting the namespace, I typically use an intermediary file. For example, this is how I organize my database queries:

```
// queries.js
import { calEventQueries } from './calevent/calevent'
import { courseQueries } from './course/course'
import { paymentPlanQueries } from './paymentplan/paymentplan'
/* etc etc etc */    

/* then I export them individually */
export { calEventQueries }
export { courseQueries }
export { paymentPlanQueries }

/* and as a group */
export default {
    calEventQueries,
    courseQueries,
    paymentPlanQueries,
}
```

Then, all I have to do is

```
import queries from '../path/to/queries.js'
```

if I want to have access to all of my queries from one variable, e.g., `queries.calEventQueries`.

This is useful, however, because I can also easily grab just one set of queries:

```
import { courseQueries } from '../path/to/queries.js'
```

---

A second option is to use the `as` keyword:

```
import { default as someOtherName } from '../path/to/mul.js'
```

but I'm not really sure this fits your use case.